# Sqlite3, electron, webpack: cannot find module abi_crosswalk.json

Tags: node.js, sqlite, webpack, electron

I'm trying to make sqlite3 work in electron in combination with webpack, babel and react.

These are the dependencies in package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "electron-packager": "^5.2.1",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.36.8",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.1.3",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
      "sqlite3": "^3.1.1"
  }
```

After running `npm install`, I ran `./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild` as described in the [documentation](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.8/tutorial/using-native-node-modules/).

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + '/src',
    entry: './entry.js',
    target: 'electron',

    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: __dirname + '/build',
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/build/'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }, {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
        }]
    }
};
```

When I add `var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();` to my code and try to run this, I'll get the following error messages:

```
`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./abi_crosswalk.json"`

./~/sqlite3/~/node-pre-gyp/package.json
Module parse failed: .../node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/package.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "name": "node-pre-gyp",
|   "description": "Node.js native addon binary install tool",
|   "version": "0.6.14",
 @ ./~/sqlite3/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 60:16-37
```

And in consequence, a bunch of modules can't be found.

Can anyone help me with this?

Edit: This is the code in bundle.js that results in the package.json error mentioned in the comments.

```
function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    "use strict";

    var versioning = __webpack_require__(310);
    var existsSync = __webpack_require__(19).existsSync || __webpack_require__(273).existsSync;
    var path = __webpack_require__(273);

    module.exports = exports;

    exports.usage = 'Finds the require path for the node-pre-gyp installed module';

    exports.validate = function(package_json) {
        versioning.validate_config(package_json);
    };

    exports.find = function(package_json_path,opts) {
       if (!existsSync(package_json_path)) {
            throw new Error("package.json does not exist at " + package_json_path);
       }
       var package_json = __webpack_require__(1133)(package_json_path);
       versioning.validate_config(package_json);
       opts = opts || {};
       if (!opts.module_root) opts.module_root = path.dirname(package_json_path);
       var meta = versioning.evaluate(package_json,opts);
       return meta.module;
    };


/***/ },
```

Comment: You can find answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914213/twilio-nodejs-react-app-cannot-find-module-net/35914931

Comment: Now I'm getting `Uncaught Error: package.json does not exist at /package.json`.

Comment: Can you provide full error message?

Comment: That's all, except for additional error messages for the modules that couldn't be found subsequently.

Comment: I've added the code that throws the error above.

Comment: Did you get node-sass working via webpack? I've been trying to get to work node-sass directly from electron but without any success.

Comment: I didn't have any troubles with node-sass, my whole configuration works like a charm now.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like `var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();` only works in the main process, but not in any render processes. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

After npm install, try this: ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild -w sqlite3 -p.
First, you should install sqlite3 and electron-rebuild .